# Proper way to writing constructors in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, dynamic-memory-allocation

**EDIT: Changed my question to something more meaningful**

If i have a class:

```
class A{
public:
     int nr;
     int *a;

     A();
};

A::A(): nr(0), a = new int[10]{}
```

This chrases, but if I have

```
 A::A(): nr(0) {a = new int[10];}
```

It works. Please explain this behavior to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nr(0)` is an initializer for the data member `nr`.

`{a = new T[10]; }` is a constructor body that assigns a value to the data member `a` *after* the initialization in the initializer list has been performed.

`{}` is an empty constructor body, it means the constructor does nothing (other than initialize `nr`, of course, since that's in the initializer list).

`a = new int[10]` in between the initializer list and the constructor body is nonsense, the syntax of the language doesn't permit it. It shouldn't compile, but if you've found a compiler that accepts it and then it crashes, you'll have to look at that compiler's documentation for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It should look something like this:

```
template<class T>
class A {
public:
     int nr;
     T *a;
     A();
};

template<class T>
A<T>::A() : nr(0), a( new T[42]) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither should compile. Proper way would be this :

- the first case : `A::A(): nr( 0 ), a( new int[5] ){}`
- the second case : `A<T>::A(): nr( 0 ), a( new T[10] ){}`

Comment: And how much memoryh would that allocate for `a`?

Comment: doh bad copy & paste. fixed now